# Correct use of php PDOStatment::rowCount()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET token=:token WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
$stmt->execute(array(':token' => $token, ':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));

echo $stmt->rowCount();
```

If I test the query in phpmyadmin I get 1 affected row, however when I use PDO objects I get 0 rows affected. Where is the mistake?

Comment: this is correct usage.

Comment: Mysql will return 0 if no WHERE condition matched or table already contain values from query.

Comment: Seems good to me... I've honestly never NOT used rowCount() as it works all the time in my case.

Comment: @YourCommonSense you were right. Post it as an answer so I can accept it. Table already had the value from the query and the update did not trigger any change :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was, as @YourCommonSense said, incorrect usage of SQL. The UPDATE does not trigger if the value from the query is already in the DB so I get 0 affected rows if I try to do that. Seems logical for performance and efficiency, but I did not expect that.